# Problem in R trying to use Keras with Caret

Tags: r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have to use Caret to fit a keras model. I am using the "mlpKerasDropout" model in Caret. I have already installed keras and tensorflow. I have the following code:

```
grid = expand.grid(activation = "relu", batch_size = 32, rho = 0.9, decay = 0,
                   lambda=0, lr = 2e-06, size = c(3,4,5))

control <- trainControl(method='cv', 
                        number=5,
                        classProbs = TRUE,
                        selectionFunctio = 'oneSE', 
                        savePredictions = "all",
                        search='grid')

model <- train(Class ~ ., 
                       data = data,
                       method = 'mlpKerasDecay',
                       preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                       metric = "Accuracy",
                       trControl = control,
                       tuneGrid = grid,
                       epoch = 100)
```

The think is that when I try to execute this code I get this error:

```
WARNING:absl:`lr` is deprecated, please use `learning_rate` instead, or use the legacy optimizer, e.g.,tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.RMSprop.
Warning: model fit failed for Fold1: activation=relu, batch_size=32, rho=0.9, decay=0, lambda=0, lr=2e-06, size=4 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer, pleasecheck the docstring for valid arguments, or use the legacy optimizer, e.g., tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.RMSprop.
```

I can't change `lr` to `learning_rate` in the gris because caret gives me an error, and I can't remove the `decay` hyperparameter neither.

So how do I use this? I checked that I have caret updated, so thats not the problem. It is possible to use it or I have to downgrade keras and tensorflow so I can use caret? I don't really know how to downgrade those libraries and use them in R normally.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput` and code so we can reproduce your problem.